# Laravel 8 login authentication through external API without database but keeping the default Laravel User & Auth features

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 & trying to create a custom authentication through external API source.

I am keeping the Frontend as Laravel without any direct database interactions & Lumen as the application data layer which interacts directly to the databases & works as an external API.

These are the authentication logic to be followed:

1. User enters his email & password.
2. Laravel will POST this credentials to a custom Lumen external API say - http://example.com/api/v1/login.
3. This external API will then validate the credentials & returns a custom Login token.
4. Then the Laravel application will use this login token across user devices as session storage & for authentication purpose.

I searched for solution but there is no detailed documentation on this.
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find any examples of this?  I need to do something very similar.